# java: output report containing pic and text

Tags: java, pdf-generation

I am currently working on a system to generate a summary report containing text and picture (preferrably .pdf format). Are there any libraries that can do this?

Comment: Depending on your requirements, generating HTML output may be the simplest solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find a lot of API or open source library from [Google](http://www.google.com). Seems like IBM [recommends](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-javapdf/) [iText](http://itextpdf.com/itext.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can try Jasper reports

http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports

Comment: Please don't try jasperreports for something so simple. Use itext instead.

Answer (score 0):

I would definetely go for [iText](http://itextpdf.com). It's quite actively developed, offers both AGPL and commercial [licences](http://itextpdf.com/terms-of-use/index.php), comes with [plenty](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keywords.php) of [examples](http://itextpdf.com/book/examples.php), and its author (Bruno Lowagie) even wrote a [book](http://itextpdf.com/book/) about it.

The latest version ([iText 5.3.0](http://itextpdf.com/history/?branch=53&node=530)) was released today (June 20th, 2012).

Moreover, the [itext](/questions/tagged/itext) community is rather active here on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

IText is good.  [JODReports](http://jodreports.sourceforge.net/) and [Docmosis](http://www.docmosis.com) are can produce PDFs and other formats and have different development focuses to iText.